# content apps for office: how to set range and read from it?

Tags: excel, apps-for-office

I am trying to develop some simple content app for office.

I want to set some ranges, and later read from it.  User has to fill few boxes and after clicking some button data should be analyzed. It would be very simple in VBA or VSTO, but I have to do it as an app for office. This office javascript API is very unnatural for me.

Some short scenario:

1. user selects some range in excel, clicks some button, and selected range is set to some public variable
2. User click button, function run and it loads and analyze data from few ranges.

Could anyone help?

In VBA:

```
sub somesub

dim rngSomeRange as range
dim rngSomeRange2 as range
dim rngCell as range
dim colValues as new collection
dim colValues2 as new collection

set rngSomeRange =range("someRange")

for each  rngCell in rngSomeRange

msgbox rngcell.value
colValues.add rngcell.value

next rngCell

for each  rngCell in rngSomeRange2

msgbox rngcell.value
colValues2.add rngcell.value

next rngCell

procAnalyze(colValues, colValues2)

end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a binding, so that you can reference it later:

```
var range = "A5:C5";
var id = "numbers";

Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(range, "matrix", { id: id });
```

Then, you can later reference this binding to set data:

```
var data = [['one', 'two', 'three']]; // 2 dimensional array (matrix)
Office.select("bindings#" + id).setDataAsync(data, { coercionType: "matrix" });
```

Please note that both `addFromNamedItemAsync` and `setDataAsync` are asynchronous methods and as such you should provide a call back method to:

1. check the result status
2. ensure the binding is created before you write to it

This is a complete example:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(range, "matrix", { id: id },
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
            // Error
        } else {
            var data = [['one', 'two', 'three']]; // 2 dimensional array (matrix)
            Office.select("bindings#" + id).setDataAsync(data, { coercionType: "matrix" },
                function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                        // Error
                    } else {
                        // Success: 'one' is in A5, 'two' is in B5 and 'three' is in C5
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly select some cells then press a button linked to this function and it will bind to these cells:

```
function bindData() { //A3
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync("matrix", { id: 'myBindingXXX' },
        function (asyncResult) {

            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage('Error bindData: ' + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            } else {
                writeToPage('Added binding with type: ' + asyncResult.value.type + ' and id: ' +
                    asyncResult.value.id, 1);
            }
        });
}
```

Now create another function to read the binding, into which you can add your own analysis as necessary.

```
function readBoundData() { //A4 note how id is used here in the binding
    Office.select("bindings#myBindingXXX").getDataAsync({ coercionType: "matrix" },
        function (asyncResult) {

            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage('Error readBoundData: ' + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            } else {
                writeToPage('Selected data: ' + asyncResult.value , 1);
            }
        });
}
```

Note that once the cells are bound you don't have to have them selected to read them.

For more information see http://microsoft-office-add-ins.com/